# How to change weird CSV delimiter?

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file that I can't open in Excel.

The CSV delimiter is  `|~|`, and at the end of a row it is `|~~|`.

I have some sample data:

```
Education|~|Name_Dutch|~|Name_English|~|Faculty|~~|International Business|~|MB|~|MB|~|ED|~~|
```

Where the Header part is: `Education|~|Name_Dutch|~|Name_English|~|Faculty|~~|`

And the Data/Row part is: `International Business|~|MB|~|MB|~|ED|~~|`

I need to find out how to change this CSV file in just a normal `,` comma separated value using a Python Script.

Comment: It looks to me the delimiter is the relatively common '|', but you should show at least a few lines of data and not just what looks like the header.

Comment: I gave a bit of the data, the header part is: Education|~|Name_Dutch|~|Name_English|~|Faculty|~~| and the Data part is : International Business|~|MB|~|MB|~|ED|~~|

Comment: always edit your post to include the extra information that was lacking from your initial post, never hide that in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assist the built-in `csv` module + `string.split()` function:

```
import csv

content = """Education|~|Name_Dutch|~|Name_English|~|Faculty|~~|International Business|~|MB|~|MB|~|ED|~~|"""

# Or read it's content from a file 

with open('output.csv', 'w+') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    lines = content.split('|~~|')
    for line in lines:
        csv_row = line.split('|~|')
        writer.writerow(csv_row)
```

it will output a file named `output.csv`

```
Education,Name_Dutch,Name_English,Faculty
International Business,MB,MB,ED
""
```

---

When dealing with a csv file, I would prefer using the `csv` module instead of doing `.replace('|~|', ',')` because the `csv` module has build-in support for special characters such as `,`

Answer (score 0):

The custom delimiters you mention seem to be unique enough so you can just do a string.replace on them. Then just write out the file.
The read and write section has all the details you need.
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

in_name = 'your_input_name.csv'
outname = 'your_outpt_name.csv'

with open(in_name, newline='') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='~', quotechar='|')
    with open(outname, "w", newline='') as outfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(outfile, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
        for row in csvreader:
            line = []
            for item in row:
                if item != "":
                    line.append(item)
                else:
                    csvwriter.writerow(line)
                    line = []
```

As `csv.reader` doesn't recognize `"~~"` as end of line, it converts it to `""`, so for `csv.writer` we repeatedly prepare the part of list (obtained from `csv.reader`) until `""` is reached.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is small, you can simply read its entire contents into memory and replace all weird delimiters found and then write a new version of it back out.

However if the file is large or you just want to conserve memory usage, it's also possible to read the file incrementally, a single character at-a-time, and do accomplish what needs to be done.

The `csvfile` argument to the `csv.reader` constructor "can be any object which supports the iterator protocol and returns a string each time its `next()` method is called."

This means the "object" can be a generator function or a generator expression. In the code below I've implemented a simple FSM ([Finite State Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)) to parse the oddly formatted file and `yield` each line of output it detects. It may seem like a lot of code, but operate very simply so should be relatively easy to understand how it works:

```
import csv

def weird_file_reader(filename):
    """Generator that opens and produces "lines" read from the file while
       translating the sequences of '|~|' to ',' and '|~~|' to '\n' (newlines).
    """
    state = 0
    line = []
    with open(filename, 'rb') as weird_file:
        while True:
            ch = weird_file.read(1)  # read one character
            if not ch:  # end-of-file?
                if line:  # partial line read?
                    yield ''.join(line)
                break
            if state == 0:
                if ch == '|':
                    state = 1
                else:
                    line.append(ch)
                    #state = 0  # unnecessary
            elif state == 1:
                if ch == '~':
                    state = 2
                else:
                    line.append('|'+ch)
                    state = 0
            elif state == 2:
                if ch == '|':
                    line.append(',')
                    state = 0
                elif ch == '~':
                    state = 3
                else:
                    line.append('|~'+ch)
                    state = 0
            elif state == 3:
                if ch == '|':
                    line.append('\n')
                    yield ''.join(line)
                    line = []
                    state = 0
                else:
                    line.append('|~~'+ch)
                    state = 0
            else:
                raise RuntimeError("Can't happen")

with open('fixed.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader((line for line in weird_file_reader('weird.csv')))
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows(reader)

print('done')
```